# Will clonezilla backup EFI partition, dual boot Windows and Ubuntu partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, clonezilla

As a follow up question to this post, [How to back up my entire system with all components?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314923/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system-with-all-components), will the Clonezilla image reinstall the EFI partition, the Windows 10 partition, and the Ubuntu partition (dual boot)?

If you make a backup image with some Clonezilla version, does it matter what version you use to reinstall it on a new hard drive?

Comment: My understanding of clonezilla is that it copies the entire disk and makes no changes whatsoever. If you copy it back to another disk it should be identical, although if the disk is larger than the original you will also have some unallocated space. It shouldn’t matter what version you use but it makes sense to use the same version for both operations if you can. If you are placing the new disk in different hardware Windows may not work, or may ask for a new license. Linux should just work unless you need proprietary drivers added that weren’t needed before

Comment: @PonJar: If you make this an answer, I will accept it. Your comment makes sense to me. I will try it on an older machine and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of clonezilla is that it copies the entire disk and makes no changes whatsoever. If you copy it back to another disk it should be identical, although if the disk is larger than the original you will also have some unallocated space. It shouldn’t matter what version you use but it makes sense to use the same version for both operations if you can. If you are placing the new disk in different hardware Windows may not work, or may ask for a new license. Linux should just work unless you need proprietary drivers added that weren’t needed before.

I once took an image of my daughter’s Windows laptop, ran Ubuntu on it for a while and later restored the Windows image. It worked perfectly.